# Request.IsAuthenticated return false after using Session in MVC using log in with Microsoft O365

Tags: session, model-view-controller, oauth, office365

as the header, my project using 2 type of authenticate, First is use OAuth Microsoft Office365 account by this code:

```
if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
        new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
        OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
}
```

And after that will claim the email information from O365 Account to access roles from local database

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    var userClaims = User.Identity as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;
    var _email = userClaims?.FindFirst("preferred_username")?.Value;
  
    //this line is to link email from O365 to local account
    ResponseLogin result = new BLL_AdminInfo().LoginWithEmailOffice(new RequestLogin { email = _email});
    if (result.result == 1)
    {
        //This lines to save local account info to check roles in MasterPage
        //If I quote this line, the O365 login function is working right
        Session[ConstantVariable.Session_Login_Rights] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new BLL_AdminInfo().GetUserRight(result.item.user_id).item);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Message = result.message;
        return View();
    }
}
```

I think the error made by the Sessiong[] lines, after call to this line, the Request.IsAuthenticated always return false, but don't know how to fix.
When I marked this line as comment, the error is gone.

Here is my logout code

```
public ActionResult SignOut()
{
    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
            OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solutions for that problems.

I install Nuget Package: Kentor.OwinCookieSaver.
After that, I add 1 code line to Startup.cs, just before

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{  

app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver(); // add this line ******
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
///...
}
```

Despite the problem is solved, I do not know how it works. I only knows that the problem is from OWIN cookie when using session.

Comment: Man you saved my day. I am not sure why someone did not vote for your answer. +1 for you.